# Rack Mount a PC?

Tags: home-server, rack

Is it possible to build a new PC and put it in a server rack with a case like this

[image]

[**http://www.rackmountmaster.com/4u-ipc-4032-rackmount-rack-mount-case.html**](http://www.rackmountmaster.com/4u-ipc-4032-rackmount-rack-mount-case.html)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It is possible to build a rack mountable case and mount it into a rack. Is that all you're asking? Seems obvious, so I feel like I'm missing something.

One other thing you might not know is that you usually need 'rails' to mount the case into the rack. They usually don't come with the case since different kinds of racks need different kinds of rails.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are putting this into a server room, it is pointless, the (fan) noise alone will drive you batty.

Comment: On the case he displayed it shouldn't be that bad.  Looks like it will accept 120mm fans.  It is the high speed fans required by the 1Us that tend to be loud.

Comment: The point is still that the case is not designed to limit noise, but allow for the most effective airflow while in a rack env.  It will still be noisy with 120mm fans, but not as noisy as 1U's or 2U's typically are.